# Limitations of using PIG with cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I intend to use PIG with cassandra for querying purpose.
I have installed Pygmalion for this purpose.
I have done little bit work on HIVE in the past which obviously have limitations of query language.
We can not implement complete language in queries.

Is there any similar limitations of using PIG too?

Comment: Are there any limitations in particular you're concerned about?  The language is pretty flexible at this point and can also be extended using UDFs.  Whatever problems you have can likely be tackled by Pig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my very recent experiences, the only limitation faced are RPC timeout, making the entire MapReduce process fail because of the 1 failure tolerance.

I have yet to solve this. If anyone can help, do share.